# Conjugacy of two subgroups of a group

Tags: gr.group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$, of index 2. Suppose $H_1$ and $H_2$ are subgroups of $G$, such that the following holds: $H\cap H_1$ and $H\cap H_2$ are conjugate in $H$, i.e., $\exists h_0 \in H$ such that, $h_0 (H \cap H_1) h_0^{-1} = H\cap H_2$.

A condition here is that, for both $i = 1,2$, $H\cap H_i \subsetneq H_i$ (proper subgroup). Thus, $H_1$ and $H_2$ are of the same order.

Are $H_1$ and $H_2$ necessarily conjugate?

If not, please suggest a nice counter-example

Comment: There are easy counterexamples (even in abelian groups) with $H \cap H_1 = H \cap H_2$.

Comment: I should have stated that $G$ is non-abelian. But a counter-example has been found there too.

Answer (score 4):

Let $G$ be the group of symmetries of a square. Let $H$ be the rotations. Let $H_1$ be generated by the rotation halfway 'round and the flip in the horizontal axis, let $H_2$ be generated by the rotation halfway 'round and the flip in a diagonal. Then $H\cap H_1=H\cap H_2$, but $H_1$ and $H_2$ are not conjugate.